# How to zoom to layer using ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I tried to get the function "Zoom to Layer" done using the following code snippet. But it does not change anything. The layer is a feature service layer, and I can see the full extent object of the layer which is not null. Any idea?

```
tree.on("dblClick", function (item, node, event) {
  var layerId=item.id[0];
  var layer = map.getLayer(layerId);

   if (!layer)
   {
    return;
   }
   else
   {
    var lyrExt=layer.fullExtent;
    var gsvc=  esriConfig.defaults.geometryService;
    var outSR = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 });
    gsvc.project([lyrExt], outSR, function(newExt) {
    map.setExtent(newExt[0],true);
   }
});
```

Comment: I found the solution. Need to convert the projection of the layer to map's projection first.

Comment: If you're using a newer version of the API you can also drop all the esri. prefixes i.e. SpatialReference vs esri.SpatialReference. You can use the class names you define in the require block argument names i.e. SpatialReference

Comment: I don't know if your code snippet is just partially copied, but as it appears now, you are missing a closing ) and }

Answer (score 1):

*From @Alex's comment indicating he found the solution :*

You "need to convert the projection of the layer to map's projection first."

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full code, try adding

> map.refresh();

Comment: map.refresh is not a function

Comment: I found where the problem is. The spatial reference's wkid of map is 102100 while the wkid of layer full extent object is 2248. Not sure how to fix this.